# Producing an error in async.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, node-async

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var async = require('async');

var MyOutputModel = function(persistenceModel, callback) {
    async.each(persistenceModel.helpOffers, function(helpOffer, asyncCallback) {
        console.log('Original source (loop)');
        //Do something ...
        asyncCallback();
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Original source (done)');
        console.log(err);
        if(err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, _this);
    });
};
module.exports = MyOutputModel;
```

I would like to test the path containing `if(err) return callback(err);`...

For doing so I see the only possibility in dependency injection with rewire (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire).

In my unit test:

```
var rewire = require('rewire');    
var MyOutputModel = rewire('...');

var AsyncMock = function() {};
AsyncMock.prototype.each = function(array, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    console.log('Inside mock!');
    callback(new Error());
};
var asyncMock = new AsyncMock();

MyOutputModel.__set__('async', asyncMock); //Rewire for require-dependency-injection

//Act
new CdObjectOutputModel(cdObjectPersistenceModel, function(err, cdObjectOutputModel) {

    //Assert
    assert(err);
});
```

However the "mock" doesn't seem to be used. In my unit test I never see `'Inside mock!'` but `'Original source (loop)'` and `'Original source (done)'` on the console. And there is no error.

Anything I do wrong? I've already used rewire for a similar use case and it worked perfectly. Or is there another approach?

Comment: How are you exporting MyOutputModel? And where are you calling rewire()?

Comment: Exporting with module.exports, rewiring in unit test (see updated code).

Comment: @mosquito87 your script contains several errors or ambiguities: first in your `AsyncMock.prototype.each` you are calling a `callback` which does not exist. Did you mean to call `errorCallback`? Second, what is `CdObjectOutputModel`?

Comment: Shouldn't you rather mock the thing that calls `asyncCallback` back, instead of `async.each`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what `rewire` does under the hood:

1. For each rewired path it'll actually read the contents of the file pointed by path which we will call the `body`
2. it'll also generate two strings, the first one is called the `prelude` and it has some helpful vars to avoid overwriting the global ones with `__set__`, e.g. if we wanted to override the global `console` as if it were local on our module the contents of the `prelude` var would be: `var console = global.console`, this awesome detection of globals which can be overridden locally is done [here](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire/blob/master/lib/getImportGlobalsSrc.js)
3. The second one is called the `appendix` and this string contains actually the definitions of the `__set__`, `__get__` and there's also `__with__` [source](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire/blob/master/lib/getDefinePropertySrc.js), each one is a function defined over `module.exports` but remember that we're still dealing with strings
4. Imagine that there's a way to create a fake/test module out of strings! That's what `wired` does, it concatenates the `prelude`, the `body` and the `appendix` in one big string and it then creates a module with `require('module')`

e.g. (remember that this is a big string)

```
// prelude start
var console = global.console
// a lot of globals that can be overriden are defined here :)
// prelude end

// body start
// I'll paste the contents of the rewire's README
var fs = require("fs");
var path = "/somewhere/on/the/disk";
function readSomethingFromFileSystem(cb) {
    console.log("Reading from file system ...");
    fs.readFile(path, "utf8", cb);
}
exports.readSomethingFromFileSystem = readSomethingFromFileSystem;
// body end

// appendix start
// generation of three functions to set the variables defined above
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, '__set__', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: function () {
    // set contents, we will see this later
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, '__get__', { ... });
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, '__with__', { ... });
// appendix end
```

So what `rewire` does is kind of create a module with this string and return it, and voila you have a magic module with three additional properties, the next step is actually find out what `__set__` does, [the `__set__` source](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire/blob/master/lib/__set__.js) boils down to the following operation:

```
function (key, value) {
  eval(key + ' = ' + value);
}
```

And that's it so now we know that executing `__set__` will just eval whatever key (which for us is any local `var`) you want, to be set as `value` but ***ONLY*** in this test/fake module.

Now going back to your problem I see that this might be the source of it:

```
new CdObjectOutputModel(...);
```

I'm assuming that `CdObjectOutputModel` is defined perhaps as a subclass of `MyOutputModel` but remember that in your test `var MyOutputModel = rewire('...');` is actually a test/fake module so you're not really overriding the original code of `MyOutputModel` but overriding kind of a *copy* of it which exists only locally, I guess that you have to rewire `CdObjectOutputModel` or perhaps locally make `CdObjectOutputModel` inherit from the rewired version of `MyOutputModel`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace callback with errorCallback and it should work fine.